# Sub-Grouping AVL tree based on nodes amount in O(log(n))

Tags: binary-trees, search-trees, avl-trees

I need to find a way to split an AVL tree based on the amount of nodes in the tree, lets assume you get a number $k$ and if the number of nodes in the tree is multiplication of $k$ you need to find the maximum of each tree in the $k$ trees.

for example:  for $k=3$

```
    3
   / \
  2   9        
 /   / \
1   4   11
```

after the split you get 3 trees (the function doesn't need to actually build those trees):

```
    2     3      9
   /       \      \
  1         4     11
```

you can also think about it like subgrouping the AVL tree to 3 sub groups {1,2},{3,4},{9,11}

the nodes should be grouped in increasing order (like printing in-order transverse and splitting it)

and the function should return 2,4,11

This problem should be solved in complexity of $log(n)$ while $n=$ the original number of nodes.

I wasn't able to think about a solution in the desired complexity, I thought about using in-order traversal but every solution is in $O(n)$.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that $n$ is divisible by $k$?

Comment: yes it is garneted

Comment: Do you have additional requirement as to how to choose which nodes are to be grouped together? Why group (3,4) and (9,11) instead of (3,9) and (4,11)? Please edit the question to include this.

Comment: the nodes should be grouped in increasing order (like printing in-order transverse and splitting it)

Comment: Does each node contain a counter of how many nodes are in that subtree? Or something similar? Because just going by the AVL invariant of height difference it seems difficult to avoid a full traversal to ensure you've got exactly the right split points. Either way, you can't do better than $O(k)$ since that's your output size, so when $k > \log n$ that is the limiting factor.

Comment: no it does not contain a counter, it can't be rank tree.

I believe it should be constructed from the beginning to K different trees but I can't figure how

Comment: I think that starting from scratch would be no better than traversing the entire tree. Also, since the size of the output is $k$, your running-time will require at least $O(k)$, just to build the output. Are you looking for an algorithm with a running-time like $O(\log n + k)$?

Comment: lets suppose that you can build the trees from scratch without considering the complexity. for example you get K=3 and than starting to get the keys of the tree so you can build K trees and not count it in the complexity